# Inquiry vs. enquiry

Tags: word-choice, orthography

I received an email today with "a simple inquiry."  I responded that her "enquiry" was quite reasonable before I realized that we were spelling the word differently.  Dictionary.com has enquiry as an alternate spelling of inquiry -- is the difference regional, archaic, a modern misspelling, or just a random variant?  Anyone know?

Comment: Vaguely related: [Insure vs. ensure](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/433/assure-vs-ensure-vs-insure)

Comment: @BrianNixon I understand you prefaced your comment with vaguely but I must disagree. Because enquiry and inquiry are actually defined with the same definition, it would have been more appropriote to use color vs. colour; or realisation vs. realization.  Insure is not defined the same as ensure. You purchase an insurance policy to insure yourself. And you leave with plenty of time to ensure that you will not be late. Insure is used when referencing the commercial practice of issuing an insurance policy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In British English, *enquiry* is most commonly used for the general meaning of “question”, while *inquiry* tends to be reserved for the sense of “formal investigation”.

Comment: Whereas in American English, the usage is more-or-less reversed: *inquiry* is just a synonym of *question*, while *enquiry* is either misspelled, or is some sort of a formal affair.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this etymology dictionary entry](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=inquiry), the original spelling was the e- form. And according to the New Oxford American, *enquiry* is "chiefly British".

Comment: If the US tabloid *National Inquirer* were published in the UK, would the name be changed to *National Enquirer*?  Inquiring people want to know...

Comment: @oosterwal: [Yes](http://www.theenquirer.co.uk/) or [no](http://www.theinquirer.net/static/aboutus) and anyway I believe the US tabloid's name is The **E**nquirer.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick:  I always get that messed up!

Comment: @oosterwal - I suppose that you could use either as an investigation carried out by journalists could carry the requisite rigour to count as an inquiry, rather than an enquiry. Then again I don't think anyone's ever implied that the _National Enquirer_ has any journalistic rigour before, so the enquiry form is probably right

Answer (score 2):

For general use it's just different variations of the same word.

In some special cases the usage differs, though. I developed software for steel business a while back, and IIRC an *enquiry* is a special form of a business proposition.