# Is this the right use of "ensure"?

Tags: word-usage

This sentence in some of my company's copy has been bothering me for a while:

"The new iDirect X3 modem comes with a one year warranty — which [company] will double to two years — insuring your peace of mind."

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/433/when-i-should-use-assure-vs-ensure-vs-insure) sort of supports it, as does [this](http://the-word-blog.com/2009/04/26/assure-vs-ensure-vs-insure/).

But this one from [Quick and Dirty Tips](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/assure-versus-ensure-versus-insure?commentid=53648), which I used to trust a lot when I used to write on a regular basis, almost seems like it's suggesting assure.

I'm pretty sure it shouldn't be 'insure' because it's the peace of mind we're ensuring. So... Insure, assure, or ensure? My gut tells me ensure, but...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most users (in the US) and most dictionaries would select *[ensure](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ensure?q=ensure)* as the logical choice

> make certain that (something) shall occur or be the case

However, [insure](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/insure) would not be wrong

> often followed by *against* to guarantee or protect (against risk, loss, etc)
>
> *we insured against disappointment by making an early reservation*
>
> often followed by against to issue (a person) with an insurance policy or take out an insurance policy (on)
>
> *his house was heavily insured against fire*
>
> *after all his car accidents the company refuses to insure him again*

The cited text refers to a warranty that the company is extending.  The company is committing financial resources to make you whole if the product fails, something tantamount to an *insurance policy*.

*[Assure](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/assure?showCookiePolicy=true)* seems less apt.  Most definitions and usage have to do with *telling* rather than *effecting*

> to cause to feel sure or certain; convince: *to assure a person of one's love*
>
> to promise; guarantee: *he assured us that he would come*
>
> to state positively or with assurance
>
> to make (an event) certain; ensure
>
> (mainly British) to insure against loss, esp of life

All said, there is a justification for each in US usage.

Comment: Yeah, that's where my mind was. I could make a case for each, but I couldn't decide which I ought to use. While the warranty refers to us fiscally guaranteeing their peace of mind, it's the peace of mind being ensured, as a psychological comfort, rather than the financial protection of the modem.

Comment: Ensure is most adequate, insure is plausible but a little awkward.

Answer (score 2):

Insure is related to business practices, like insurance. Assure is promising something to remove doubt ("I assure you that I will be home on time.") and ensure is guaranteeing a condition ("The airbags and other safety features ensure that you will be safe.")

In this case, I think that it could be changed to "assuring you have your peace of mind" to make it clearer, but in the current context I would agree that ensure would be correct because you are guaranteed peace of mind. Maybe your company means "insuring" literally though since the topic is a warranty.

Comment: That is a good point, I guess I'm just not a fan of the sentence structure since it is the peace of mind that's being [as/in/en]sured.

Answer (score 0):

One meaning of *insure* is *guarantee*, which is I suspect what they meant in this case.

Answer (score -2):

The [prefix *en-* means "to make" or "to cause to be"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/en-#etymonline_v_8621). So here *en*-sure means "to make sure".

Comment: PLEASE use standard English. It is very difficult to understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: But it's right. The _en-_ prefix (or suffix, or both) is an old Germanic causative/inchoative marker, and generally verbs and adjectives with them (like _ensure, enlighten, blacken, enjoy, tighten,_ and _ennoble_) normally mean 'to become `X`' or 'to cause/make/force to become `X`'.